# Modify function calls within a formula

Tags: r, splines

Suppose you are working on a regression model and at least one of the predictors
is estimated via splines, e.g.,

```
library(splines)
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

fit <- lm(price ~ bs(depth, degree = 5) + bs(carat, knots = c(2, 3)) * color, 
          data = diamonds)
```

The above fit is for illustrative purposes and has no meaningful reason for
being.

Now, lets keep the same basic formula, but change the knot locations for both
depth and carat.  The update needs to take place in a dynamic way such that it
could be part of a bigger MCMC method (number of knots and knot locations to be
determined either by either a reversible jump or birth/death step).

I'm well aware of the `update` and `update.formula` calls, but I don't believe
that these tools will help.  The following pseudo code should illustrate the
behavior of the function I'm planning to develop.

```
foo <- function(formula, data) { 

  # Original Model matrix, the formula will be of the form:
  Xmat_orig <- model.matrix(formula, data)

  # some fancy method for selecting new knot locations here
  # lots of cool R code....

  # pseudo code for the 'new knots'.  In the example formula above var1 would be
  # depth and var2 would be carat.  The number of elements in this list would be
  # dependent on the formula passed into foo.
  new_knots <- list(k1 = knot_locations_for_var1, 
                    k2 = knot_locations_for_var2)

  # updated model matrix: 
  # pseudo code for that the new model matrix call would look like.
  Xmat_new <- 
    model.matrix(y ~ bs(var1, degree = 5, knots = new_knots$k1) + bs(var2, knots = new_knots$k2) * color, 
                 data = data)

  return(Xmat_new) 
}
```

Can someone suggest a way to modify the `knots` call within either a `bs` or
`ns` call dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possibility that isn't as picky about what is input to your function. Consider this

```
newknots <- function(form, data, calls=c("bs","ns")) {
    nk <- function(x) { 
        sort(runif(sample(1:5, 1), min = min(data[[x]]), max = max(data[[x]])))
    }
    rr <- function(x, nk, calls) {
        if(is.call(x) && deparse(x[[1]]) %in% calls) {
            x$knots = nk(deparse(x[[2]]))
            x
        } else if (is.recursive(x)) {
            as.call(lapply(as.list(x), rr, nk, calls))
        } else {
            x
        }
    }
    z <- lapply(as.list(form), rr, nk, calls)   
    z <- eval(as.call(z))
    environment(z) <- environment(form)
    z
}
```

So this isn't exactly a trivial function, but hopefully it's not too bad. The idea is that we can convert a formula to a list object that we can recursively investigate. That's what the internal `rr` function is doing. It takes a list, and then looks at each of the elements. It looks for calls to `bs` or `ns` and when it finds them, it replaces the `knots=` parameter.

Here we use the `kn` function to create a new set of knots for a given variable name which is passed in as a string. We simply need to return a list of values appropriate for that variable.

Finally I need to turn the list back into a formula and I make sure our new object has the same environment as the original formula. So this actually does create a new formula object leaving the original intact (you may replace the original value if you wish).

Here's an example of how you would call/use this function.

```
f <- price ~ ns(carat, knots=c(1,3)) * color + bs(depth, degree = 5) + clarity
newknots(f, diamonds)

# price ~ ns(carat, knots = c(2.09726121873362, 3.94607368792873
# )) * color + bs(depth, degree = 5, knots = c(44.047089480795, 
# 47.8856966942549, 49.7632855847478, 70.9297015387565)) + clarity
```

So you can see that the knots were added and replaced according to our new rule. I'm not sure what other features you may need, but hopefully this will give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, @MrFlick, this was helpful.  While not exactly what I was looking for, your work spurred me in the right direction to find a working solution.

Comment: How is it different than what you were looking for?

Comment: I've provided my answer to to this SO question.  The only major difference is where/how the new knots are generated and placed into the formula.  I like your answer a lot, and I will likely incorporate most of it into a more robust solution than the one I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substitute` function in R, which:

> substitute(expr, env)
>   substitute returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression expr, substituting any variables bound in env.

For example:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> x <- 1
> x + y
Error: object 'y' not found
```

Because `y` is not defined. Now use `substitute`:

```
> (expr <- substitute(x + y, list(y=2)))
x + 2
> eval(expr)
[1] 3
> z <- 2
> (expr <- substitute(x + y, list(y=z)))
x + 2
> eval(expr)
[1] 3
```

In your example:

```
f1 <- eval(substitute(price ~ bs(depth, degree = deg) + bs(carat, knots = knts) * color, 
                       list(deg=5, knts=c(2, 3))))
f2 <- eval(substitute(price ~ bs(depth, degree = deg) + bs(carat, knots = knts) * color,
                       list(deg=6, knts=c(3, 4))))

fit1 <- lm(f1, data=diamonds)
fit2 <- lm(f2, data=diamonds)
```

In general, you can write a function that wraps the `substitute` call, say:

```
formula.with.knots <- function(degree, knots) {
  f.expr <- substitute(price ~ bs(depth, degree = deg) + bs(carat, knots = knts) * color, 
                        list(deg=degree, knts=knots))

  eval(f.expr)
}

f <- formula.with.knots(5, c(2, 3))
fit <- lm(f, data = diamonds)
summary(fit)
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `substitute()` to just create the formula

Comment: You are right. I will modify my answer. BTW, I like your new book.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas are all bound to an environment. So one option is to create the formula separately with variables for the arguments you might want to change and assign these variables values in the environment of the function.

```
f <- as.formula("price ~ bs(depth, knots=d_knots) + bs(carat, knots=c_knots) * color", 
                list2env(list(d_knots=c(2,3), c_knots=c(3,2))))
```

I've defined two defaults for `d_knots` and `c_knots`. To then modify these values:

```
environment(f)$d_knots <- c(2,3)
environment(f)$c_knots <- c(3, 2)
```

You can then supply the formula to the modeling function

```
fit <- lm(f, data=diamonds)
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

Thank you @MrFlick, your solution is exactly what I was looking for.

#### #original post

Thank you to @MrFlick and @hadley, their responses on SO and Twitter help me to find a working solution.  This method will need refinement, but seems to be working for my immediate needs.

The function `with_new_knots` defined below will parse the a `formula` and modify elements via `terms`.  (I should also thank the author of the `survival` package, Terry Therneau, as I dug through that code to see how formulas were manipulated when functions such as `strata` were included in formulas.)  I can already think up use cases where this function would fail, but the important part is that the outline of the method exists and I can extend and improve it later.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(splines)
set.seed(42)

with_new_knots <- function(frm, data, iterations = 5L) { 
  # extract the original formula
  old_terms   <- terms(frm, specials = c("bs", "ns"))

  # reconstruct the rhs of the formula with any interaction terms expanded
  cln     <- colnames(attr(old_terms, "factors")) 
  old_rhs <- paste(cln, collapse = " + ")

  # Extract the spline terms from the old_formula 
  idx              <- attr(old_terms, "specials") %>% unlist   %>% sort
  old_spline_terms <- attr(old_terms, "factors")  %>% rownames %>% extract(idx)

  # grab the variable names which splines are built on
  vars <- all.vars(frm)[idx]

  # define the range for each variable in vars
  rngs <- lapply(vars, function(x) { range(data[, x]) })

  # for each of the spline terms, randomly generate new knots
  # This is a silly example, something clever will replace it. 

  out <- replicate(iterations, 
                   {
                     new_knots <- lapply(rngs, function(r) { 
                                         kts <- sort(runif(sample(1:5, 1), min = r[1], max = r[2]))
                                         paste0("c(", paste(kts, collapse = ", "), ")")
                             })

                     new_spline_terms <- 
                       mapply(FUN = function(s, k) { sub(")$", paste0(", knots = ", k, ")"), s) },
                              s = old_spline_terms,
                              k = new_knots)

                     rhs <- old_rhs
                     for(i in 1:length(old_spline_terms)) { 
                       rhs <- gsub(old_spline_terms[i], new_spline_terms[i], rhs, fixed = TRUE)
                     }

                     f <- as.formula(paste(rownames(attr(old_terms, "factors"))[1], "~", rhs))
                     environment(f) <- environment(frm)
                     return(f)
                   }, 
                   simplify = FALSE) 
  return(out) 
}
```

## example use:

Here a statistically meaningless model is presented and modified via `with_new_knots` to illustrate the results, one `formula` object is updated so that the `spline` calls within the formula have been updated.

```
f <- price ~ ns(carat) * color + bs(depth, degree = 5) + clarity
with_new_knots(f, diamonds)


orig_fit <- predict(lm(f, data = diamonds))
new_fits <- with_new_knots(f, diamonds) %>%
            lapply(., function(frm) { predict(lm(frm, data = diamonds)) })

dat <- data.frame(orig_fit, new_fits)
names(dat)[2:6] <- paste("new knots", 1:5)
dat <- melt(dat, id.vars = NULL)
dat <- cbind(dat, diamonds)

ggplot(dat) + 
aes(x = carat, y = value, color = color, shape = clarity) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_point(aes(y = price), alpha = 0.1) + 
facet_wrap( ~ variable, scale = "free")
```

[image: Illustration of the different models with different knots]

Comment: I see. So this will not replace existing knots such as the case in your example in the original question. It seems to just add a second `knots=` parameter.

Comment: If a `spline` call with explicit knots is passed to `with_new_knots` the resulting `formula` would not be useful.  A problem I think I can remedy by incorporating parts of your suggested solution.  

Replacing the `knots=` call will likely be a must for this code to function well.

Comment: OK. I've also updated my solution to behave more like yours (same inputs).